# Let $U_g$ be the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/g\mathbb{Z}$ . . .

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $U_g$ be the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/g\mathbb{Z}$. Then $U_g$ is a subgroup of itself. For every unit $c$ of $U_g$, show the coset, $cU_g = U_g$.

Show that the product of the elements of $U_g$ = the product of the elements of $cU_g$.

Conclude that $c^{\varphi(s)} = 1$.

I know for the last part that it is concluding Euler's Theorem.

I tried to do this problem by visualizing $U_{20}$ but that did not get me very far. Please help!

Comment: what is the meaning of unit in $U_n$? it is just a group no? not a ring

Comment: The question does not specify but from my own knowledge I do not believe it is a ring.

Comment: I think the question should read as follows: for every invertible element $c \in \mathbb{Z}/g\mathbb{Z}$ show that $cU_g = U_g$.

Comment: That could be another way to write it, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the wording of the question is what I have stated in the comment. Let $x \in cU_g$, then $\exists \, y \in U_g$ such that $x=cy$. Since both $c$ and $y$ are invertible, therefore $\exists, p,q \in\mathbb{Z}/g\mathbb{Z}$ such that
\begin{align*}
cp & \equiv 1 \pmod{g}\\
yq & \equiv 1 \pmod{g}.
\end{align*} 
This gives us 
$$(cy)(pq) \equiv 1 \pmod{g}.$$
Thus $x=cy$ is invertible, hence lies in $U_g$. Likewise you can show the other containment $U_g \subseteq cU_g$.

Since $U_g=cU_g$, therefore $U_g=\{u_1,u_2, \ldots\}=\{cu_1, cu_2, \ldots\}=cU_g$. Thus $cU_g$ is simply the same set with perhaps a permuted list of the elements of $U_g$. In which case
\begin{align*}
u_1 \cdot u_2 \dotsb & = (cu_1) \cdot (cu_2)\dotsb\\
u_1 \cdot u_2 \dotsb & = c^{\phi(g)}u_1 \cdot u_2\dotsb\\
1 & \equiv c^{\phi(g)} \pmod{g}
\end{align*}
This is Euler's theorem.